# Using grunt-contrib-less inline. Generate one CSS file foreach LESS file

Tags: css, gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less

I am attempting to use the [grunt-contrib-less](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less) grunt task to compile my [less](http://lesscss.org/) files to css.  What I would like to do is compile them inline, so that each `.less` file creates a single `.css` file.

Workflow:

1) Initial file system:

```
someFolder2
    joe.less
    rachel.less
    someSubFolderA
        jake.less
        bob.less
someFolder4
    someSubFolderB
        ally.less
```

2) run `grunt less`

3) File system:

```
someFolder2
    joe.less
    rachel.less
    joe.css
    rachel.css
    someSubFolderA
        jake.less
        bob.less
        jake.css
        bob.css
someFolder4
    someSubFolderB
        ally.less
        ally.css
```

I have played around with various options but I can't figure out how to do this.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  This is the starting point grunt task I have been using:

```
less: {
    paths: [
        "src/someFolder2/**/*.less",
        "src/someFolder4/**/*.less"
    ],
    options: {
        // outputSourceFiles: true
        // compress: true,
        // sourceMap: true,
        // sourceMapFilename: "jake.txt"
        // outputSourceFiles: true
    }
}
```

This will (I think) concat all of the less files into a single CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define task for grunt

```
options: {
    paths: ["<%= cfg.dist %>/src/less"],
    sourceMap: true,
    rootpath: "<%= cfg.dist %>/",
    relativeUrls: false,
    cleancss: false
},

test: {
    files: [
        {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= cfg.dist %>/src/less/',
            src: ['*.less'],
            dest: '<%= cfg.dist %>/build/css/',
            ext: '.css'
        }
    ]
}
```

/src/less/ - location of your less files

/build/css/ - folder where css will be generated